# What is an "elk" beyond the Wall?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In *A Song of Ice and Fire* we are told that Coldhands rides a large *elk* with a great rack of antlers.  Well, the word *elk* has different meanings in the UK and the US.  Which is it?

UK meaning of "elk" *Alces malchis*, called "moose" in the US and Canada:

[image: Elk or moose]

US meaning of "elk" *Cervus canadensis*, perhaps called "wapati" in the UK:

[image: Elk]

Could it be that GRRM, being American, intends us to visualize the thin antlered, Cervus Canadensis (US ELK), or the thick antlered, alces malchis (US moose, UK ELK)?

Comment: The Latin name for the kind of the kind of moose found in America is *Alces alces* so I think the European version is a different species.

Comment: the most likely answer is 'some imaginary species that is elk-like but unique to the world of ASoIaF'

Comment: Maybe the extinct [Irish Elk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_elk)?

Comment: I'm just reading *A Storm of Swords* now and pictured it as the US elk, although I'm from the US, so that's not too surprising. I suspect @MikeEdenfield is correct. I haven't watched *Game of Thrones*, do they not show it in that?

Comment: are the coldhands english or american ?

Comment: Interesting question. Turns out artists have depicted him with both: http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Category:Images_of_Coldhands

Comment: @JohnWinkelman I don't read the books but I'm really hoping someone puts together some evidence toward it being the Irish Elk - makes sense with the mammoths that also live up there (in the show, at least)

Comment: I always pictured the former ("Moose") as what Coldhands rode, simply because the "elk" is more of a deer in my eyes. In Sweden, we have "moose", which are called "Älg" (sounds similar to Elk) that look like the former. Also, the moose is more badass. It would look a little bit silly if Coldhands came riding on Bambi's father.

Comment: Of course, it's worth remembering that [when he wrote ASOIAF, GRRM didn't know what horses looked like](http://www.clickhole.com/blogpost/when-i-started-writing-game-thrones-i-didnt-know-w-292), `;-)` so it stands to reason that he didn't know elk either...

Comment: I note that in the 2017 calendar https://www.amazon.com/Song-Fire-2017-Calendar-Illustrations/dp/110196569X/ it is depicted as a moose

Comment: @TLP I'm not sure you've ever seen an American elk.  They're frickin' massive.  Bigger than a lot of horses, so easily ridable.  Pictures really don't do them justice, but 300 kg is a small one.

Answer (score 10):

It appears to be left unclear as to what type of antlers the elk have in the books. Although from the text it can be inferred that the antlers are more similar to that of the US elk.

> From a nearby oak a raven quorked, and Bran heard the sound of wings as another of the big black birds flapped down to land beside it. By day only half a dozen ravens stayed with them, flitting from tree to tree or **riding on the antlers of the elk**. The rest of the murder flew ahead or lingered behind. But when the sun sank low they would return, descending from the sky on night-black wings until every branch of every tree was thick with them for yards around. Some would fly to the ranger and mutter at him, and it seemed to Bran that he understood their quorks and squawks. They are his eyes and ears. They scout for him, and whisper to him of dangers ahead and behind.
>
> <sub>A Dance with Dragons, Bran I</sub>

Obviously it is possible to ride on the antlers of both of the types of elk but it is easier to ride on the thinner ones. That quote doesn't really point in either direction but:

> In the very shadow of the Wall the wildlings made ready, winding thick coils of hempen rope around one shoulder and down across their chests, and lacing on queer boots of supple doeskin. The boots had spikes jutting from the toes; iron, for Jarl and two others, bronze for some, but most often jagged bone. Small stone-headed hammers hung from one hip, a leathern bag of stakes from the other. **Their ice axes were antlers with sharpened tines**, bound to wooden hafts with strips of hide. The eleven climbers sorted themselves into three teams of four; Jarl himself made the twelfth man. "Mance promises swords for every man of the first team to reach the top," he told them, his breath misting in the cold air. "Southron swords of castle-forged steel. And your name in the song he'll make of this, that too. What more could a free man ask? Up, and the Others take the hindmost!"
>
> <sub>A Storm of Swords, Jon IV</sub>

The axe blades would be easier to make from the UK elk though these are ice axes so it would be just as easy to make them from the US elk. Again it is unclear.

However, the [2017 ASOIAF calendar](http://georgerrmartin.com/notablog/2016/02/04/new-2017-soif-calendar-artist-didier-graffet-grrminion/) points to the elk being like the UK version although the antlers are more of a mix between the two:

[image: Coldhands in the 2017 calendar.]

Note that the elk in the calendar above looks more like the extinct [Irish elk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_elk):

[image: Irish elk]

Comment: That calendar picture look like the extinct https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_elk, not the moose/Eurasian Elk. The antlers are a match, and it has a more standard deer head than the moose's distinctive round snout and relatively short, stocky neck.